# Prestashop: Variable price based on product processing

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I have one more complex questions, so I will split it. Since it is basically one topic I don't wanna to split it into two separate threads. I would be grateful either for any information about an existing module, or any idea how to do this by yourself.

**Question #1**

If I understand the product price calculation process in Prestashop I basically have two options:

- Price defined on a product
- Price defined on a product combination

What I need, though, is to provide customer with more advanced calculation. Let's say products can be assembled and equipped with multiple different tags. Therefore, I can't use product_attribute (Combination) as no matter if I assemble the product or not, it is always the same product with only one physical amount of products on stock. As if it was a Combination, and customer order the product assembled, the stock would only be decreased on for this Combination, but not for the other Combinations. Hope that makes sense.
Example:

```
Painting #348 + frame + additional service  = $500 
Painting #348 + frame                       = $375
Painting #348                               = $345
```

It is even more complicated as these sort of "additional services" are only available to relevant products. Another products may offer customers different "additional services".

Question #2
For scenarios from Question #1, I need also to differentiate the price. So if a customer wants to buy 300 pieces of a painting with frame it is $10 cheaper per product. If the amount is over 500, it's $25 cheaper etc. I know I can do this for a regular product or a combination, but how would you do it if the price would be custom just like in Question #1.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i have understood your question completely or not but, as far as i understood here is your solution:

You may have a product:

```html
XYZ Pizza 
(with different toppings like chicken, red meat)
(also have sizes Small, Medium and Large)
```

Off course you will have different prices for different combination.

So what you can do is:

- Create a product XYZ Pizza with price zero and quantity zero.
- Add combinations to the product, so you just need to add actual price of that
  combinations, no headache of increase decrease calculations for price.
  It is super easy if you are using csv import.

And don't worry as long as you have a single combination with some price for that product the zero prices won't be shown on your website.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually initially I was about to use combinations pretty much the same way as you suggest. The thing is that I always have one piece of "pizza" for multiple different combinations. Therefore, if one buys one of those combinations, the stock amount will be decreased for just that particular combination but not for the rest of combinations of the same product. Is that clear what I'm saying? :-)

Comment: That is the right way..suppose you have your stock: Pizza(Ch/S)-10, (Ch/M)-10,(Ch/L)-10..so on, So if a customer buys a Ch/S pizza, then your stock of Ch/S becomes 9. That is right thing. Please note: You are initially giving 0 stock to the product (XYZ Pizza, while creating product) `Abbreviations Ch-Chiken, S/M/L - Small/Medium/Large` Please mention if this is not in your case.

Comment: Thanks Anil! Well, I think this is not what I'm looking for. Let's say I have products like this: _Pizza_, _Mac&Cheese_ etc. Each product has multiple combinations: Pizza(Ch,S), Pizza(Ch,M), Pizza(Ma,S), Pizza(Ma,M) etc. So I have two different combinations **Pizza** **with** **chicken** and **Pizza** **Margerita**. So I need to have the quantity on Combination, but there is still an option to buy _Small_ or _Medium_ pizza. 
As far as I know I can only have quantity defined either on Product (Pizza) or Combination (Chicken, Margerita). So if I used S/M options in combinations it wouldn't work.